# c++ std::string use overwrites values

Tags: c++, stdstring

What am I doing wrong here?  Apparently aval is overwritten
when I call getbbb.  Expected output is:

```
test A aval: "aaa"
test B aval: "aaa"
```

Actual output is:

```
test A aval: "aaa"
test B aval: "bbb"
```

File testb.c:

```
#include <string>

// g++ -o tempa testb.c && ./tempa

std::string getaaa() {
  return std::string("aaa");
}

std::string getbbb() {
  return std::string("bbb");
}

int main(
  int argc,               // num args, including pgm name
  char * argv[])          // args
{
  const char * aval = getaaa().c_str();
  printf("test A aval: \"%s\"\n", aval);

  getbbb();

  printf("test B aval: \"%s\"\n", aval);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" using an invalid pointer. `aval` is invalid at the `;` of it's declaration

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const char * aval = getaaa().c_str();` leads to *undefined behavior*.

`getaaa()` returns a *temporary* `string` object that is destroyed when the full expression that created it is finished (ie, on the `;`), which is after you have grabbed the `string`'s data pointer. Thus, the pointer is left dangling, pointing at freed memory.  Any subsequent reading from that pointer is *undefined behavior*.

Since the `string` object from `getaaa()` is destroyed and its data freed before `getbbb()` is called, `getbbb()` is allowed to reuse the same memory for its own `string` object. This is not *guaranteed*, but it is *possible* (and clearly the case in your situation).

To solve this, save the *temporary* `string` object from `getaaa()` to a local `string` variable before grabbing the pointer:

```
const string sval = getaaa();
const char * aval = sval.c_str();

printf("test A aval: \"%s\"\n", aval);

getbbb();

printf("test B aval: \"%s\"\n", aval);
```